# A box contains four silver rings and one gold ring. what is the probability of getting a gold ring in n tries?

Tags: probability

A box contains four (4) silver rings and one (1) gold ring. What is the probability of getting a gold ring in n tries(Without replacement)?

Is the answer n/5?

Comment: Are the selections made with or without replacement?

Comment: Without replacement, I edited the question, Thanks

Comment: In that case, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct.

One way to see this is to observe that the probability of getting a gold ring in $n$ tries can be found by subtracting the probability that only silver rings are obtained in $n$ tries from $1$.  Let $X = n$ be the event that a gold ring is obtained within $n$ tries.
\begin{align*}
\Pr(X = 1) & = 1 - \frac{4}{5} = \frac{1}{5}\\
\Pr(X = 2) & = 1 - \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} = 1 - \frac{3}{5} = \frac{2}{5}\\
\Pr(X = 3) & = 1 - \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = 1 - \frac{2}{5} = \frac{3}{5}\\
\Pr(X = 4) & = 1 - \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = 1 - \frac{1}{5} = \frac{4}{5}\\
\Pr(X = 5) & = 1 - \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{0}{1} = 1 - 0 = 1 = \frac{5}{5}
\end{align*}
so the probability of obtaining a gold ring in $n$ tries is indeed $n/5$.

Alternatively, observe that a gold ring is equally likely to be anywhere in the sequence of selections.  Hence, the probability that a gold ring will be selected during the $k$th trial is $1/5$.  By linearity of expectation, the probability that the gold ring will be obtained in $n$ tries is
$$\Pr(X = n) = n \cdot \frac{1}{5} = \frac{n}{5}$$

Comment: (+1) In R: `n = 1:5;  dhyper(1, 1,4, n)` returns 
$0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0.$